# smalltalk block - can I explicitly set the returning value and stop executing the block?

Tags: block, smalltalk

The return value of #value: message, when sent to a block, is the value of the last sentence in that block. So `[ 1 + 2. 3 + 4. ] value` evaluates to 7.
I find that hard to use sometimes. Is there a way to explicitly set the returning value and stop executing the block?

For exercise, try rewriting this block without using my imaginary #return: message and see how ugly it gets. I must be missing something.

```
[ :one :two |
  one isNil ifTrue: [ two isNil ifTrue: [ self return: nil ] ifFalse: [ self return: true ] ].
  two ifNil: [ self return: false ].

 (one > two)
  ifTrue: [ self return: true ]
  ifFalse: [ (one < two)
              ifTrue: [ self return: false ]
              ifFalse: [ self return: nil ]
            ].
]
```

EDIT: `self return: sth` really is nonsense, but it does make sense at **some** level :)

Answer (score 7):

There's nothing like a guard clause - `blah ifTrue: [^ foo]` - inside a block, because `^` is a non-local return, returning from the method calling the block rather than the block itself.

Big blocks - like big anythings - should be refactored into smaller, more understandable/tractable subparts, but sometimes that's not always possible. I mean this answer to suggest options to try when you *can't* really simplify in the usual ways.

If your block is really that complicated, and you can't get it simpler (splitting it up delocalises the information too much, for instance) then perhaps you can use an explicit return value. In particular, if your block doesn't return `nil` you could do something like

```
[:one :two | | result |
    result := (one isNil and: [two isNil]) ifTrue: [false].
    result ifNil: ["do one thing, possibly setting result"].
    result]
```

If your block can return `nil`, you'll need another sentinel value:

```
[:one :two | | result marker |
    result := marker := Object new.
    (result == marker) ifTrue: ["do one thing, possibly setting result"].
    result]
```

Lastly - and I hesitate to suggest this - you could do this:

```
[1 + 2.
thisContext return: 5.
3 + 4] value
```

which returns `5`.

(Verifying how this interacts with `^` and inlined selectors like `#ifTrue:ifFalse:` left as an exercise for the reader.)

Answer (score 2):

It seems that your code tries to handles *nil* like an *infinity* value when comparing *one* and *two*. The following code may be more readable depending on the context:

```
a := [:one :two |
    | x y |
    x := one ifNil: [Float infinity].
    y := two ifNil: [Float infinity].
    (x = y) ifTrue: [nil] ifFalse: [x > y]]
```

A useful feature of #ifTrue:ifFalse:, #ifNil:ifNotNil: and similar *testing* methods is that they return the value of the block that gets evaluated. e.g. `(4 > 1) ifTrue: ['greater'] ifFalse: ['not-greater']` evaluates to *'greater'*. This feature often makes it possible to return a value from a nested block in tail position.

When the code inside a block gets too complicated I suggest your refactor it to a method. But see Frank's answer for workarounds.

**Edit:**

As pointed out in the comments the code above assumes numbers. I also came up with something that works with other comparable objects:

```
a:=
[ :one :two |
  true caseOf: {
    [one = two]->[nil].
    [one isNil]->[true].
    [two isNil]->[false]
  } otherwise: [one>two]]
```

That #caseOf: construct is rarely used but it's certainly better than `thisContext return:`

Comment: If you evaluate that block with `value: nil value: nil` you'll get `nil`, not `infinity`.

Comment: @milan When *one* and *two* are nil you get nil with both my code and yours. In your code: `[ :one :two | one isNil ifTrue: [ two isNil ifTrue: [ self return: nil ] ...`   in my code (Infinity = Infinity) so it returns nil

Comment: Oh, ok. You almost got it right without answering the real question I made :) But my code works for Strings and anything.

Comment: Right. I was only thinking of numbers. ;-)

Comment: @milan I added another version using `#caseOf:otherwise:`

Answer (score 2):

You'd like to implement some break, continue, exit...
The usual way to control flow in Smalltalk is with blocks.
So one funny solution is to use a helper method with a Block return value to break the flow, like described [here](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/help-smalltalk/2008-06/msg00077.html) .

```
Object>>exitThru: aBlock
    ^aBlock value: [:result | ^result]
```

Now, let see how to use it:

```
| aBlock |
aBlock :=   [ :one :two |
    self exitThru: [:exit |
        one isNil ifTrue: [ two isNil ifTrue: [exit value: nil ] ifFalse: [ exit value: true ] ].
        two isNil ifTrue: [ exit value: false ].
        one > two ifTrue: [ exit value: true ].
        one < two ifTrue: [ exit value: false ].
        exit value: nil] ].

#(('abc' nil) (nil nil) (nil 'def') ('y' 'abc') ('y' 'y') ('y' 'z'))
    collect:
        [:pair |
        aBlock value: pair first value: pair last ]
-> #(false nil true true nil false)
```

**EDIT** my first version was unnecessarily complex, can't remember what lead me to an additional indirection:

```
| aBlock |
aBlock :=  [:wrapOne :wrapTwo |
    self exitThru: [:exit |
        [ :one :two |
        one isNil ifTrue: [ two isNil ifTrue: [exit value: nil ] ifFalse: [ exit value: true ] ].
        two isNil ifTrue: [ exit value: false ].
        one > two ifTrue: [ exit value: true ].
        one < two ifTrue: [ exit value: false ].
        exit value: nil ]
            value: wrapOne value: wrapTwo ] ].
```

Well, more funny than usefull, I hope you will find more simple and expressive way to code.

Comment: +1 Clever stuff. People should check out the [link](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/help-smalltalk/2008-06/msg00077.html) for a concise example.