# Can not call "function" in GNU Smalltalk

Tags: smalltalk, gnu-smalltalk

I want to define block and call it in this way:

```
add := [ :a :b |
    ^(a+b).
].

n := add value: 1 value: 2.
```

But when I try it, I get an error:

```
$ gst 3.1.st 
Object: 3 error: return from a dead method context
SystemExceptions.BadReturn(Exception)>>signal (ExcHandling.st:254)
SystemExceptions.BadReturn class(Exception class)>>signal (ExcHandling.st:151)
SmallInteger(Object)>>badReturnError (Object.st:1389)
UndefinedObject>>executeStatements (3.1.st:3)
```

How can I call a function in GNU Smalltalk?

Well, I dropped the return statement, and this code works fine. But when I try to define more complicated function, for example:

```
nod := [ :a :b |
    (a=b) ifTrue: [a].
    (a>b) ifTrue: [nod value: (a-b) value: b].
    (a<b) ifTrue: [nod value: a value: (b-a)].
].

n := nod value: 1 value: 2.
n printNl.
```

It prints nil. And if I define with "early exit":

```
nod := [ :a :b |
    (a=b) ifTrue: [^a].
    (a>b) ifTrue: [nod value: (a-b) value: b].
    (a<b) ifTrue: [nod value: a value: (b-a)].
].

n := nod value: 1 value: 2.
n printNl.
```

It gives me the same error: return from a dead method context.

I solve this problem in this way:

```
nod := [ :a :b |
    (a=b) ifTrue: [
        a
    ] ifFalse: [
        (a>b) ifTrue: [nod value: (a-b) value: b] ifFalse: [nod value: a value: (b-a)].
    ]
].

n := nod value: 1 value: 2.
n printNl.
```

But I think, it is not beautiful way.

Comment: For the fun of it, you could play with somthing like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7547750/smalltalk-block-can-i-explicitly-set-the-returning-value-and-stop-executing-th/11532045#11532045

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Drop the return statement (`^`) from your code and it will work fine.

In smalltalk, returning exits the method in which the return statement appears. It's used for early exits, for example `a < b ifTrue: [^a] ifFalse:[^b]`.

In this case, you don't want the block to exit the containing method, you just want it to evaluate to something when sending it `value:value:`. A block evaluates to the last statement in it, so just make it a regular statement there and it will do the trick.

The error message you got, by the way, also explains the problem: you're trying to return `3` from a method which is already dead.

Comment: Ohh... Not exactly :( I upgrade my question.

Comment: @DmitriyM regarding your edit - the way you tried last is the way to do it, it's definitely the most smalltalk-ish approach. Your attempt with consecutive `ifTrue` statements is incorrect; in fact, the 1st and 2nd blocks in that `nod` implementation have no side effect and so are meaningless. Remember, it's only the last statement which is returned - and the last statement is the last `ifTrue`.

Answer (score 4):

Remove non-local return (^), parenthesis, and period inside a block. And try doing it again.

Answer (score 3):

You've already accepted an answer to your original question, then redefined your question.

To answer your updated question, you could use the fact that a block returns the value of its last statement, and use a local variable:

```
nod := [ :a :b | |r|
    (a = b) ifTrue: [r := a].
    (a > b) ifTrue: [r := nod value: (a-b) value: b].
    (a < b) ifTrue: [r := nod value: a value: (b-a)].
    r
].
```

I am curious, though, about the context. I suspect this might more appropriately be defined as a selector/method for a class.

---

By the way, the above implementation will go into an infinite recursion if either argument is negative.

The simplest way to get the results you're after would be:

```
nod := [ :a :b | a gcd: b ].
```

:)

Comment: Nice solution! Thank you very much!